# Setting output_buffer in Rails' own tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, testing

I'm writing a testcase against Rails' CacheHelper. To achieve the desired result, I need to be able to set the `output_buffer` manually. Currently Rails' cache_test.rb test has the following test for the function in question:

```
def test_fragment_caching
   get :fragment_cached
   assert_response :success
   expected_body = <<-CACHED
Hello
This bit's fragment cached
CACHED
   assert_equal expected_body, @response.body

   assert_equal "This bit's fragment cached", @store.read('views/test.host/functional_caching/fragment_cached')
end
```

This would be a fine template for me but I need to be able to set manualle the `output_buffer` that is accessed in cache_helper.rb's CacheHelper. Any ideas how to set this in the test?

Comment: Why are you writing a test for `CacheHelper`? Did you find a bug in it?

Comment: Yep. https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/2080